# How to use MAT?

Tags: android, memory, out-of-memory

I'm running out of memory on an android emulator.  I attempt to find the source of the problem.

Here's my heap data.

[image]

What's concerning if i'm reading it right is that I have 3.1 MB free but the largest chunk available is only 179.336 KB?

I could use some direction in identifying the source of the problem. Here's the histogram from MAT sorted by shallow heap. Which one's should I look for because the largest shallow heap isn't necessarily the largest retained heap?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at the video in the link

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

The guy shows how to use Mat Analyzer to find memory leak and fix the same with an example

The blog in the link below is written by the same guy in the video

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

Here's another tutorial for the same

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ryAYxLNpt8

Answer (score 0):

To find the largest retain heap of an object, you will want to right click on an object, and check the "path to GC roots excluding weak references"